# how to integarate drools in apache flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, drools, apache-flink

there is a flow of events in kafka now for processing events (filtering, enrichment, and so on) using apache flink. But very often I'll get used to writing small things like filtering in the form of a flink as it's overshadowed by such rules it's very easy to do through drools without having to write code so whether there really are ready-made things to integrate such solutions, ideally, I want to get something like a QRadar.